# K3b is missing vcdxbuild vcdxminfo and vcdxrip, how can I install it?

Tags: k3b, vcd

I can't install this programs using apt-get, I think I have to add the package.

By the way, how can I find the packages for new softwares when I have only the software name? Google is not helping much on this (I did a search for vcdxbuild, and found nothing useful)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install vcdimager package. That is all.

To install: use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vcdimager
```